# SSH Connect to Ec2 instance using IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have created a IAM user and I am trying to connect to it using SSH. I have tried OPenSSH and Putty but unable to connect using either of these.

In browser I am logged in with root user.

1. Create key pair using below command:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Rectangle diagram at the end says  RSA 2048 , SHA 256 algo is used.

2. Logged into Amazon web console. Navigate to IAM user created by me and uploaded public key obtained using step 1.

```
IAM -> User -> Security Credential -> Upload ssh public key.
```

3. Option1 of OpenSSH

```
  C:\Users>ssh -i "C:\Users\UserName\.ssh\id_rsa" IamUser@awspublicIp
The authenticity of host 'awspublicIp' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nLBtVuJWST7tf7FJGqjxaNYFGQfJw1z/5U3tOGC9byE.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'awspublicIp' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
IamUser@awspublicIp: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Here I am douting ECDSA  as the culprit , don't know from where this is getting picked.

Option2 of using putty has also not worked.

Documentation suggested [Creating or importing a key pair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#prepare-key-pair) is confusing.

I have used the option of creating keyPair in pem format. While connecting from OpenSSH , it says `Permission denied(public Key)`. So I have created public key via `ssh-keygen -y -f "C:\Users\Downloads\test.pem"`.

Uploaded this public key to IAM -> User -> Security Credential -> Upload ssh public key.
Still, I am unable to connect.

Can anyone help me with this? I am confused now, basically, I wanted to do SSH connect to EC2 using IAM account instead of Root.

Comment: What is your _actual_ goal? Do you wish to connect via SSH using a keypair, or do you wish to connect to an instance by using IAM credentials? They are separate methods.

Comment: I want to connect to my EC2 instance using IAM user instead of root user. I can log in to web console using IAM user's credentials. I think ec2-instance-connect is a solution to it as highlighted by Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pem key that you're adding here is actually for use within the [code commit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) service.

If you want to connect to the instance via IAM credentials then you have 2 choices available:

- You can setup and connect via the [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html). This method will allow you to connect via the normal terminal method over SSH.
- You can connect via the AWS CLI using the [Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html). This method will be carried out by using the AWS CLI to start a session from any command line with the CLI installed.

The documentation you've linked above is for generating a PEM for use with the default user of your instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try.

Comment: Sure, best of luck :)

Comment: HI, ec2-instance-connect looks like a solution to my problem. I can see it started in 2019 and providing a window of 60s to do ssh login. But I am unable to download ec2-instance-connect.  I have got below response after running commands.

1)  uname -srv
Linux 4.14.181-108.257.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 27 02:43:03 UTC 2020

2)  sudo yum install ec2-instance-connect
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package ec2-instance-connect available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: EC2 Instance Connect requires Amazon Linux 2 or Ubuntu 16.04 or later. It appears that you are running **Amazon Linux 1**.

Comment: In Amazon linux 2 it should be pre installed. For version 1 , we should explicitly install. But yum install command gives empty results to me.

Comment: I have upgraded my AMI to Amazon2 linux now I can do instance connect for root user successfully. To enable instance connect for IAM user. i have created below custom policy and attached to group of which my IAM user is part of, still, I am unable to instance connect for IAM user.
Warning I receive while saving policy is  "This policy does not grant any permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition. For details, choose Show remaining Learn more"

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:MyRegion:MyAccountId:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:osuser": "ec2-user"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Are you sure the error is for this policy? Is this the only statement you have?

Comment: Just to simplify I have removed my custom policy and added below 2 AWS provided policy to IAM Group.  AdministratorAccess and EC2InstanceConnect. 
Now from ec2 screen, Connect -> EC2 instance connect -> User Name -> MyIAMUser . But connection fails. If I enter ec2-user in UserName, the connection succeeds. Can you try this activity at your side?

Comment: Connection fails because of security group or because of the credentials?

Comment: as I said ec2-user is able to connect i.e security group is open on ports 80 and 22.  As it is SSH connection, I am not providing any credentials explicitly.

Comment: How are you connecting (browser or terminal)? Do you have an exact error string you're being returned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217247/discussion-between-sauribabu-and-chris-williams).